# Update on Change

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a textbox(1) wich automaticly calculates and displays the input after a textbox(2) is updated. 
Textbox(1) is set to enabled = false so the user can not input any values as it updates automatically.

I want to display the number in Textbox(1) after it has changed/updated.
I have tried using the AfterUpdate property for Textbox(1) but does not work because the user is not physically updating the value.

Is there any way to detect a change when the number changes in the textbox and store the number in another textbox?

Comment: "and displays the input after a textbox(2) is updated." so why are you not using events from textbox(2) to detect an update?

Comment: I tried using afterupdate and lost focus for textbox(2) but does not work because in Textbox(2) user is not inputing any information.

Comment: Where is the user entering data that causes the calculation? How is textbox2 updated and where does textbox1 come into the whole affair? You should name your controls with meaningful names.

Comment: The user enters the data in a datasheet within a subform. After the data is enetered it should automatically do all the calculations in the parent form. The calculations in the parent form should be displayed on another form. I know it sounds complicated but thats whats requried.

Comment: Then you use the subform update events.

Answer (score 2):

As already said by others, if the user enters stuff into `Textbox2` and you want to display that in `Textbox1`, then you have to use the events of `Textbox2`, not `Textbox1`!

The easiest way would be to use the `AfterUpdate` event of `Textbox2`.
Example:

```
Private Sub Textbox2_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Textbox1 = "Text from second textbox: " & Me.Textbox2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the OnLostFocus (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlostfocus.aspx) to tell when the user's focus leaves the textbox.

Otherwise you can use OnKeyPress (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress.aspx) and a timer to tell how long since the last keystroke.

Comment: but textbox(1) in disabled. The user can not click or enter data. The data updates automatically and only displays a number e.g. total

Comment: you could use the above answer on your textbox(2) because you need to put the event on your textbox(2)